# Dart / Flutter Date Format

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the format of the date string returned from the API. The below date format input string is working fine in java but not in Dart.

```
 DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS aa")
          .parse(notification.createdat);
      final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('EEE M/d/yy h:mm a');
      final String formatted = formatter.format(tempDate);
```

Here is the error retured:
[image]

Comment: It might be because `SEP` is all uppercase. You could test this by just putting a static string with `Sep` as month into the parse function. Check the proper syntax here https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax

Comment: @Er1 Thanks, It worked. I think it would be helpful for others if you can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because `SEP` is all uppercase. You could test this by just putting a static string with `Sep` as month into the parse function.

```
DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS aa")
          .parse('30-Sep-20 12.50.18.518880 pm');
      final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('EEE M/d/yy h:mm a');
      final String formatted = formatter.format(tempDate);
```

Check the proper syntax here https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS aa")
          .parse(notification.createdat);
      final DateFormat newDate = DateFormat('EEE M/d/yy h:mm a').format(tempDate);
      print("${newData.days}");
```