# How can I convert open weather api dt to Date using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, date, dart

I've been working on weather forecast app and now I'm trying to convert dt to simple date format, I get the following error:

In forecast.dart

```
class WeatherData {
  String? placeName;
  DateTime? date;
  num? temperature;
  num? feels_like;
  num? pressure;
  num? humidity;
  num? wind_speed;

  WeatherData({
    this.placeName,
    this.date,
    this.temperature,
    this.feels_like,
    this.pressure,
    this.humidity,
    this.wind_speed,
  });
  @override
  String toString() =>
      '${placeName ?? 'unknown'}  ${date ?? 'unknown'}  ${feels_like ?? 'unknown'}   ${temperature ?? 'unknown'}   ${pressure ?? 'unknown'} ${humidity ?? 'unknown'}  ${wind_speed ?? 'unknown'}';

  WeatherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    placeName = json['city']['name'];
    date = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(json['list'][0]['dt'] * 1000,
        isUtc: false);
    temperature = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    feels_like = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    pressure = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    humidity = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    wind_speed = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
  }
}
```

weatherData.dart

```
import 'package:forecast/models/weather_data.dart';

class ForecastData {
  final List list;

  ForecastData({required this.list});

  factory ForecastData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['list']?.map((e) => e)?.toList(growable: true) ?? [];
    List weatherData = [];
    list.forEach((e) {
      WeatherData w = WeatherData(
          placeName: json['city']['name'],
          date: e['dt'],
          temperature: e['main']['temp'],
          feels_like: e['main']["feels_like"],
          pressure: e['main']['pressure'],
          humidity: e['main']['humidity'],
          wind_speed: e['wind']['speed']);

      weatherData.add(w);
      print(weatherData);
    });

    return ForecastData(list: weatherData);
  }
}
```

output

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime?'
```

How can I convert dt to simple date using flutter? I'm using openweather api. any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are using `fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch` in your first snippet. Why not just use it in the second snippet as well. BTW your API seems to deliver milliseconds (because you are multiplying your timestamp with 1000). If that's the case, you can just use `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` without multiplying.

Comment: thank you. I followed your solution and was able to get the value for date. however, the output printed out is not what I had expected.. I/flutter ( 4463): [London  1970-01-20 00:52:26.400  9.77   10.45   1010 85  6.02] I'm pretty sure 1970-01-20 00:52:26.400 is the value for date.. how can I format this value to simple date?

Comment: If you get `1970-01-20 ...` as your date, you probably need to use `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e['dt'] * 1000)` after all. On formatting a date see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706355/displaying-date-in-custom-format-flutter or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155022/dart-flutter-date-format

Answer (score 0):

You can see how it is implemented in this package - [weather_pack](https://pub.dev/packages/weather_pack).
Here's how it can be done:

```dart
/// Safely unpacks a unix timestamp from a [Map] object,
/// i.e. an integer value of milliseconds and converts this to a [DateTime] object.
DateTime? unpackDate(Map<String, dynamic>? M, String k) {
  if (M != null) {
    if (M.containsKey(k)) {
      if (M[k] is int) {
        final int millis = (M[k] as int) * 1000;
        return DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millis);
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```